# Toggle between data streams and make them pause/play with RxJs

Tags: rxjs

I have `getUserData$(userId)` which returns user data based on dropdown select and if not provided with userId returns a default stream,
`pauser` reflects pause/play status,

```
var clicks = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
    .map(function() {
      var pauseStatus= state.get('dashboard').get('pauseStatus')
      return pauseStatus;
    });       
  var pauser = new Subject();
  clicks.subscribe(pauser);
```

I want to toggle between different streams and make them pausable as well:

```
var sources = [];
var newSub =()=>{return new Subject();} 
sources.push(newSub());
getUserData$().subscribe(sources[0]);

//if new user is selected from dropdown
if(user_id){
sources.push(newSub());
getUserData$(user_id).subscribe(sources[sources.length-1]);

}
var pausable = pauser.switchMap(paused => paused ? Observable.empty() : sources[sources.length-1]);

pausable.subscribe(function(result){...})
```

but it keeps jumping between two streams rendering both ,what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz demo?

Comment: the problem was I defined observables in an export func and was calling them from two views,now I have updated code with a checker that if user_id is changed,completes observable in all views and rerenders current with new user_id I will post the code soon